# Why is Google Photos getting the dates wrong on my uploaded photos?

Tags: google-photos

I am uploading photos from an oddball camera (a MyFirst Camera 3), and while Windows 11 has no problem displaying the correct "Date Taken" data, Google photos is confused and is showing a very wrong date.

What gives?
How can I fix this?

(answer below)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's an EXIF tag that everybody else seems to ignore that Google Photos takes very seriously, called
`GPS Date/Time`.  What's frustrating about this scenario is that the Windows explorer windows hide this EXIF tag.

Anyways, to fix you want to use a tool that will strip that tag.

For example, The exiftool command line is:

```
exiftool.exe  -gpsdatestamp= -gpstimestamp=  *.JPG
```